# OpenGL Bitmap-Font color blending antialised

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, color-blending

I wrote myself a program that generates me bitmap-fonts from any installed font to png.
I use png for two reasons:
  1. Preserve alpha values
  2. It's an open format

It also generates a xml-file so that I can read single chars.
The exported version of this bitmap-font uses a white font color to allow simple color-blending.
However, when I use antialiasing while exporting the bitmap-font my color-blending gets ugly,
because the antialiased border preserver the original white of the font causing half-colored edges.

Does anyone know how to dodge this effect without using a realtime font-renderer or having to forego antialiasing.

Edit1:

As you can see, when I use orange to blend, I get a white border.

[image: As you can see, when I use orange to blend, I get a white border.]

With black, this border is not visible because black is 0f 0f 0f 1f (RBGA).
The second the blending color has some similarity to white it leaves a "whitened" border caused by half transparent pixels from the antialiasing.

Edit2:

Here is some code showing how I load the image to gl and how I init gl:

initGL:

```
protected void initGL() {
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f); // Black Background
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthMask(false);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix
    doResize();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

load image to gl:

```
public static Texture loadTexture(String resName, BufferedImage image) {        
    int textureID = glGenTextures(); // Generate texture ID
    Texture texture = new Texture(resName, textureID);

    int texWidth = image.getWidth();
    int texHeight = image.getHeight();
    texture.setWidth(texWidth);
    texture.setHeight(texHeight);

    ByteBuffer buffer = convertImageData(image, texture);

    texture.bind();

    // Setup wrap mode
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // Setup texture scaling filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Send texel data to OpenGL
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, (image.getColorModel().hasAlpha() ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    // Return the texture ID so we can bind it later again
    return texture;
}
```

Comment: What is your blend function (GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)? If memory serves, the proper solution is to use (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).

Comment: I updated the main post.
As you can see, I use (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).